# Wrong media-query triggers on iPhone 6

Tags: css, iphone, media-queries

I have 2 mediaqueries:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 550px), (max-height: 550px) and (min-device-width: 500px)
```

and

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 550px), (max-height: 550px) and (min-device-width: 800px)
```

Why does the last one overwrite the first one? Min-device-width of the iphone 6 in portrait is not 800px, right?

I also tried min-width instead of min-device-width

Comment: For iphone 6 use this @media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px)
 - From: http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma is an `OR` argument. That means in this case that as long as the `max-width: 550px` is true the device does not care about the following arguments.

Removing the comma and replacing them with an `and` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Like KittMedia said, you should replace the comma with an "and" so that both statements are executed.

Example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) and (max-height: 550px) and (min-device-width: 800px) {
     p {display: none}
}

<p>This will disappear on an iPhone 6</p>
```